How to create token using spl-token create-token with --enable-metadata
I am following this tutorial on how to create a token with metadata
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token
but when it comes down to creating the token, and trying out this command
spl-token create-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb \
 --enable-metadata my_own_keypair.json

Above returns this Error: Program(IncorrectProgramId)
If --enable-metadata is removed, the token is created without any issues.
I want to update the metadata using a command similar to the one below.
spl-token initialize-metadata niceG6oxHmPcXVdNaUoECzWXn8Jz8fA5Q99QauJ4Gun \
  'Some Token' 'SOME' \
  'https://bafybeidfm65jzvz4zeesxp6ybinkitvpd27klk6yspstrtw5fuy5w27lkq.ipfs.w3s.link/metadata.json'

Also, is there a way to specify a maximum supply when creating a token, if not, how do I dos something like that?

Most likely, my_own_keypair.json is already being used in another program, because that command works on my own testing. Or you might be using an out-of-date local solana-test-validator.

Initialized a token 22 mint with the metadata extension like this.
Try removing the quotes and see if it there is a change.
spl-token initialize-metadata teseCZW7zZkyFJvHpDp7gB6rgvzYJa65XdPWL3Y7ivf Kobeni22 KB2 https://github.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/blob/main/metadata.json --update-authority  4kg8oh3jdNtn7j2wcS7TrUua31AgbLzDVkBZgTAe44aF

ref: spl-token documentation
As for supply, I am uncertain whether that can be capped using the CLI(I haven't worked with token extensions extensively yet).
You might want to also check out the JS examples

what's a token 22 ?

Token.extensions program, previously called token program
